# Import shapefile with PgAdmin III

Tags: qgis, postgis, import

I am trying import shapefile with PgAdmin III during "QGIS geoalgorithms"

[image]

but I can't find mistake.

[image]

I don´t have "Shapefile to PostGIS Import Tool" and DB manager doesn´t work.

Comment: pgAdminIII is an administration tool for PostgreSQL, not a database. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  All questions here should include the *exact* versions of software in use and the exact error in **text** form, so that it is 1) legible on all devices, and 2) searchable via text engines

Comment: use the QGIS DB Manager to connect to and import data into your PostGIS database - then you can use pgAdmin3 to query / manage your database tables

Comment: QGIS DB Manager doesn´t work

Comment: What do you mean by DB Manager doesn't work? It doesn't work at all or it's not importing the file to Post GIS? If it's the latter what is going wrong? Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import after you load the shapefile table in pgadmin using postgis shapefile plugin and connect to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: I don´t have postgis plugin and I don´t it install